# Programatically modify related products

Tags: related-products, product-relations

I'm trying to programmatically manipulate the product relations in a Magento store.

From what I've read, setRelatedLinkData should be the way to go.

As I simple test, I'm just trying to replace a products related products with nothing (i.e. an empty array), however it's not working - the product in question is still showing the related product in the backend.

The test code I'm working with is:

```
                $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());
                $linkData = array();
                print_r($linkData);

                $product->setRelatedLinkData($linkData);
                echo "Save\n";

                $r = $product->save();
```

As mentioned above however the product still has a related product when I reload it in the backend.

NOTE: I don't *only* want to remove related products, eventually I want to be able to add new ones as well, so a DELTE FROM... SQL query isn't what I am looking for. However if I can't get it to work to remove products, then it's certainly not going to work to add them, so one step at a time :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data = array();
$link = $product->getLinkInstance();
$link->getResource()->saveProductLinks($product, $data, $link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Had a quick look at the documentation to work out how to add products as well and both work - thanks!