# Re-save entire catalog's related products field via SSH php script?

Tags: related-products

I'm trying to re-save the "related products" field for each item in the catalog via SSH. I've seen other answers do something similar so I've attempted to replicate it with what little understanding I have, but still can't manage to get the script working.

Any advice appreciated.

```
require_once 'abstract.php';
class Resave_Products extends Mage_Shell_Abstract
{
    public function run()
    {
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('id');

    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())
        $link = $product->getLinkInstance();
        $link->getResource()->saveProductLinks($product, $data, $link::LINK_TYPE_RELATED);
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is $data in your code? you got any error? how did you run this could you share the code.

Comment: @MeenakshiSundaram R Thanks for the reply. Honestly, I spliced together two different answers because I'm the ultimate newb and I though it made sense. From [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52968/programatically-modify-related-products) and [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/65081/a-simple-way-to-re-save-all-products) I run it through my SSH terminal, "php filename.php".

Answer (score 2):

This defines the `Resave_Products` class but does not *do* anything. Add the following at the bottom:

```
$shell = new Resave_Products();
$shell->run();
```

If you have a look at the other files in `/shell` you will see the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You're right, I realized that shortly after I posted this, but forgot to update it here. Unfortunately, the overall script still doesn't work. Like I said before, I amateurly spliced two other scripts together as I'm a newb so it's likely broken. Any other ideas?